# Sorting Asc and Desc by data attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to go about sorting a list based on two data attribute. I want to sort it by data-name and data-id, both ascending and descending. Please Help me Guys!

```
<a href="#" class="pure-button sort2">Name A - Z <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="pure-button sort1">Name Z - A <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
<div class="sort-list"> 
  <div data-id="1" data-name ="afres">Anchor</div>
  <div data-id="2" data-name="bottom">Anchor</div>
  <div data-id="3" data-name="curves">Curves</div>
</div>
```

```js
function sortMeBy(arg, sel, elem, order) {
  var $selector = $(sel),
    $element = $selector.children(elem);

  $element.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = a.getAttribute(arg),
      bn = b.getAttribute(arg);

   if (order == 'asc') {
      if (an > bn)
        return 1;
      if (an < bn)
        return -1;
    } else if (order == 'desc') {
      if (an < bn)
        return 1;
      if (an > bn)
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  $element.detach().appendTo($selector);
}

$(document).on('click', '.sort1', function() {
  sortMeBy('data-id', 'div.sort-list', 'div', 'desc');
});
$(document).on('click', '.sort2', function() {
  sortMeBy('data-id', 'div.sort-list', 'div', 'asc');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="pure-button sort2">Name A - Z <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="pure-button sort1">Name Z - A <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
    <div class="sort-list"> 
      <div data-id="5.5" data-name="afres">Anchor</div>
      <div data-id="2.2" data-name="bottom">Bottom</div>
      <div data-id="3.1" data-name="curves">Curves</div>
    </div>
```

I was trying to return `a > b` but it doesn't work.
Please help me!

Comment: Your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/jn2eLd99/

Comment: @kulaeff   I insert fiddle in my code, it doesnt work if data attribut ex: 3.5, 5.5, 6.6

Comment: Well, it does actually work. If we click 'Name A-Z', the items will be sorted in the descending order: Anchor (5.5), Curves (3.1), Bottom (2.2). And if we click 'Name Z-A', the items will be sorted in the ascending order: Bottom (2.2), Curves (3.1), Anchor (5.5). What's wrong?